AttributeError: type object 'AutoModelForCausalLM' has no attribute 'from_pretrainted'
I see video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C3vvE9g1K9w . My jupyterlab
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, pipeline

model_name_or_path = "TheBloke/CodeLlama-7B-Instruct-GPTQ"
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrainted(model_name_or_path, device_map = "auto", trust_remote_code = True, revision = "main")

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, use_fast = True)

prompt_template = f'''[INST] Write the Python code to perform Binary search 
[/INST]

'''

pipe = pipeline("text-generation", model = model, tokenizer = tokenizer, max_new_tokens = 512, do_sample = True, temperature = 0.7, top_p = 0.95, top_k = 40, repetition_penalty = 1.1)

print(pipe(prompt_template)[0]['generated_text'])

error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[15], line 4
      1 from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, pipeline
      3 model_name_or_path = "TheBloke/CodeLlama-7B-Instruct-GPTQ"
----> 4 model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrainted(model_name_or_path, device_map = "auto", trust_remote_code = True, revision = "main")
      6 tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name_or_path, use_fast = True)
      8 prompt_template = f'''[INST] Write the Python code to perform Binary search 
      9 [/INST]
     10 
     11 '''

AttributeError: type object 'AutoModelForCausalLM' has no attribute 'from_pretrainted'


How to fix it?

There's a typo in your code it's .from_pretrained, you have an extra t
